# im working on leadtools and trying to configure it to work on https

Tags: ssl, leadtools-sdk

i'm using lead tools web scanner and trying to enable it to work on HTTPS.

> Blockquote

can i get some help here

Answer (score 0):

It appears you tried to quote something in your question but it did not show correctly.

In any case, if you’re using the current version 20 of LEADTOOLS, see this forum post with detailed information on [How to Enable HTTPS in the LEADTOOLS Web Scanning Host](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12633-).

If you’re using the previous version 19, there’s an older [article that discusses that version here](https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/enable-https-web-scanning-host-demo/).

If neither of these pages helped you, send full details about what you tried and what problems you ran into to the support address support@leadtools.com. Our email support is free regardless of which version of LEADTOOLS you’re using.